# ListView in Android, handler for clicking item

Tags: android, listview

I have an activity in Android which uses a ListView. When I click on an item in the ListView, I would like to be able to determine which item was clicked. I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setContentView(R.layout.listr);

   //setupDB();  
   //populateList3();
   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
   lv.setClickable(true);

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      
        Toast.makeText(ListRecords.this,"Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });
```

}

My layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  

     android:id="@+id/Linear03lr"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:orientation="vertical"  
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">  


 <!--Put form controls here-->  
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"

 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="400dp" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/previousbutton"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"

        android:text="Previous Menu"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing here to be able to intercept clicks on the Listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to use [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), then you simply have to over-ride `onListItemClick`.

Comment: When I use ListActivity the program crashes when the activity starts

Comment: @eljainc OK, that's probably easily fixed.  Run `adb logcat` to find out what exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are populating the listview (right now there is nothing in it), the clicked item's position is given in the 'position' argument of your onitemclick method.

While developing, I suggest logging information with `log.v("text1","text2")` and check the DDMS console to see what your application is actually executing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I do have the listview populated properly.  The logging is not important to me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the clickListener set up correctly. With this code are you getting the Toast popup when you click on an item in the list? The int position variable that gets passed to the `onClick()` method will let you see which item in the list has been clicked.

Comment: I'm not getting the Toast popup, but I do see the list